# Extract Objects from a Model using Filter on the 2nd Model Class

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following few Classes in my `models.py`

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class Challenge(models.Model):
    match_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    totalPlayers = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="pending")
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Challenge_Participant(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="pending")
```

What I am trying to do is actually access all the `Challenge objects` in which the logged in user is participating (so in Challenge_Participant, player will be equal to `request.user.account` and challenge will be equal to the challenge being searched) and exclude those challenges which are created by the User itself (because the challenges in which user is participating himself, there is an object of Challenge_Participant for this case as well)

I am unable to make a query to extract all the Challenges in which `request.user` is part of.

I am trying to do something like this,

```
challenges = Challenge.objects.filter().exclude(created_by = request.user.account)
```

I want to Filter Out those challenges in which the Challenge_Participant objects have user equal to the logged in user and challenge equal to the challenge being searched. **I can't seem to figure out what I can write in the Filter comamnd in such a case**

From those results of challenges, I am excluding all the challenges which are created by the user himself.

Comment: Have you made custom user model?

Comment: @SunderamDubey no I haven't, I am using the default User Model.

Comment: So why you queried `request.user.account`, User model has no field account.

Comment: It should be `Challenge.objects.exclude(created_by__user=request.user)`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey No no, I did actually make an Account Class in which (the default User Model) is used as a Foreign key. That account class holds name of the user and etc. and that Account Class is being used as a foreign key in Challenge Class (which is why I used reuqest.user.account)